# javascript multiple field creation issue on limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have added button that creates multiple year i want to stop creation of field when number of year is 10. how can i stop this. on year 10?

also i want to disable button once year 10 field is created.

```js
let i = 2;
document.getElementById('add-new-person').onclick = function () {
    let template = `
        <h3>Year ${i}:</h3>
        <p>
            <input name="people[${i}][first_name]">
        </p>
`;

    let container = document.getElementById('people-container');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = template;
    container.appendChild(div);

    i++;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

[type=submit] {
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
}

.add-new-person {
  background: #6688dd;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <div id="people-container">
        <h3>Year 1:</h3>
        <p>
            <input name="people[1][first_name]">
        </p>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="add-new-person" class="add-new-person">Add! new year</a>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use button element instead of `a` tag. This works better then an a tag. Also, to prevent default behavior of button click we use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method. So our page is not reloading each time we click.

To disable your button just set the button `attr` to [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) to `true` when the limit reaches years `> 10`

I have added comments in each line to reflects what happening as well.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
//Button
let button = document.getElementById('add-new-person')

//Limit of elements
let i = 2;

//Click function
button.onclick = function(e) {
  //Disable default behabviour
  e.preventDefault()

  //Appending extra years
  let template = `
        <h3>Year ${i}:</h3>
        <p>
            <input name="people[${i}][first_name]">
        </p>`;
  
  //Checking if the limit is > 10 then we are disabling the button
  if (i > 10) {
    //Disable button
    button.disabled = true;
    console.log('Button Disabled')
    //Return false
    return;
  } else {
    let container = document.getElementById('people-container');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = template;
    container.appendChild(div);
    i++;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

[type=submit] {
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
}

.add-new-person {
  background: #6688dd;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div id="people-container">
    <h3>Year 1:</h3>
    <p>
      <input name="people[1][first_name]">
    </p>
  </div>
  <button id="add-new-person" class="add-new-person">Add! new year</button>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope it is useful**

```js
let i = 2;
document.getElementById('add-new-person').onclick = function () {
//check it if i<=10 do it
  if(i <=10){
    let template = `
        <h3>Year ${i}:</h3>
        <p>
            <input name="people[${i}][first_name]">
        </p>
`;

    let container = document.getElementById('people-container');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = template;
    container.appendChild(div);

    i++;
    }
    //if i>10 add deactive class to element
    else{
    document.getElementById("add-new-person").classList.add("Deactive");
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

[type=submit] {
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
}

.add-new-person {
  background: #6688dd;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.add-new-person.Deactive{
background: gray;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <div id="people-container">
        <h3>Year 1:</h3>
        <p>
            <input name="people[1][first_name]">
        </p>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="add-new-person" class="add-new-person">Add! new year</a>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Why you custom CSS and have extra lines of code when you can just use attr `disabled` to disable  a simple HTML element.

Comment: There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks.
that's a <a> tag

Comment: You can just use a `button` which is better. For `a` you can disable `a` tag by removing its `href`

Comment: I believe it can be done with the least change
 maybe "<a>" tag  used all the page or pages and need more changes may be made